# Popup notification in gmail?

Tags: javascript, php, gmail-api

What is this popup notification in gmail, and how can I replicate it? I assume it is javascript. I'd like to use it in an outside google web project but I don't see anything in the API about what it is called.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pop-up message that you see is not produced by the Gmail, it's already in your Spreadsheet when updating Custom Menus.

If you want something like that, then you can use [Dialogs in Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) using the Google Apps Script.

You can either use [Alert dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs), [Prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) or [Customs dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) that you want for your Docs or Spreadsheet.

Just visit the link of different dialogs, it will give you a sample code on how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a browser  extension.

Try out https://www.inboxsdk.com